# MS SQL Conditional Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Query :

```
  SELECT * FROM Customer c
  LEFT JOIN  Invoice I ON  I.InvcNum = C.Cust_InvcNum
```

some thing changed and the join does not work because there is no consistency in the data in the 'Cust_InvcNum'. So now when it does not find the record for the join or if it is null it needs to check for another condition.

```
 LEFT JOIN Invoice I ON I.InvcNum = (SELECT p.InvcPrefix FROM Prefix WHERE p.DealerID = I.DealrID )  + '-' + I.InvcNum
```

second join I do works but it is taking too long for it get me data. Is there any other way to do this.

Earlier it used to be

Join on  I.InvcNum = C.Cust_InvcNum
  both the columns has the same data like   DlrCd-InvcNum i.e both the columns 1234-A789
  but not it could match on the above data or  now the column 'InvcNum' in invoice table
  can  be populated like  Dlrd-InvcNum or InvcPrefix-InvcNum

So InvcNum = 1234-A789 but CustNum = I94-A789
so we need to check if the  for InvoicePrefix-InvcNum

Comment: Can you post some of the sample data that you are trying to join on?  It might be easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: This can probably be handled without the subselect, by using an `OR Cust_InvcNum IS NULL AND othercondition` in the join's `ON` but agree, we need to see some data.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan to see where the performance issue is?

Comment: I added some data examples

Comment: I don't see how it works for you. You are joining  `Invoice` table with `Prefix` table, so `customer` table is not joined with 'Invoice' table, there is no connection. You need to give sample data from both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c 
  LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT i.InvcNum, p.InvcPrefix + '-' + I.InvcNum AS pInvcNum 
             FROM Invoice i LEFT JOIN Prefix p ON i.DealrID = p.DealrID
             ) ip ON c.Cust_InvcNum = CASE WHEN c.Cust_InvcNum = ip.InvcNum 
                                           THEN ip.InvcNum 
                                           ELSE ip.pInvcNum END
```